# Minio S3 index rotation

Tags: amazon-s3, docker-compose, bucket, minio

Is there a way to configure minio to delete indexes older than a week? I am running minio in container and need a way to automatically clean up after some time.

```
minio:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    networks:
      - loki
    volumes:
      - /var/minio:/data
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: "minioadmin"
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: "minioadmin"
    command: server /data --address ':9000' --console-address ':9001'
    #/var/lib/docker/containers/<container id>/<container-id>-json.log
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: 1m
        max-file: "3"
        tag: "common.logging.minio.docker"

  createbuckets:
    image: minio/mc
    networks:
      - loki
    depends_on:
      - minio
    entrypoint: >
      /bin/sh -c "
      /usr/bin/mc config host add myminio http://minio:9000 minioadmin minioadmin ;
      /usr/bin/mc rm -r --force myminio/loki;
      /usr/bin/mc mb myminio/loki;
      /usr/bin/mc policy set public myminio/loki;
      exit 0;
      "
```

Comment: do you mean objects?

Comment: what do you mean by `indexes`??

Comment: Yes, i ment objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
  "Rules": [{
      "Expiration": {
        "Date": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "ID": "OldPictures",
      "Filter": {
        "Prefix": "old/"
      },
      "Status": "Enabled"
    },
    {
      "Expiration": {
        "Days": 7
      },
      "ID": "TempUploads",
      "Filter": {
        "Prefix": "temp/"
      },
      "Status": "Enabled"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I can use /usr/bin/mc ilm import --bucket myminio/loki to set the rule.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**